# php looping array - html table

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of `n` elements, of the form:

```
array (
    array ("FOO", "BAR"),
    array ("FOO", "BAR"),
    array ("FOO", "BAR")...
)
```

I would like to loop over the array and display them on an HTML table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? $bigArray = array( array("foo", "bar"), array("foo", "bar"), array("foo", "bar") ); ?>
<table>
<? foreach($bigArray as $a) { ?>
    <tr><? for($j=0; $j <= 5; ++$j) { ?><td><?= $a[$j] ?></td><? } ?></tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can prototype with your favorite html editor and plug the commands in.  Note that this only works when your server supports short_tags.

Comment: you can replace the `5` with your bound (i.e. `$j < $max_elements`)

Answer (score 1):

Try a foreach loop.

Foreach:

```
<?
$bigArray = array( array("foo", "bar"), array("foo", "bar"), array("foo", "bar") );
?>
<table>
<?
    foreach($bigArray as $a)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$a[0]."</td><td>".$a[1]."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```